# Login is not working in java JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a login in java using a java jpanel. However my code does not work, as it does not print out "worked" as it is supposed to when the user clicks continue after typing "pass" into the textfield and I do not understand why? Here is my code, thank you in advance:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class login implements ActionListener {
public JTextField x = new JTextField(10);
public JFrame f = new JFrame("Login");
public JButton B = new JButton("continue");

public login()
{
    f.add(new JLabel("Login"));
    f.add(x);

    B.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(B);

    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setSize(500,300);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String textFieldValue = x.getText();

    if(textFieldValue=="pass")
    {
        System.out.println("worked!");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    new login();


}

}
```

I have also tried to use the password as a string, like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 public class login implements ActionListener {
public JTextField x = new JTextField(10);
public JFrame f = new JFrame("Login");
public JButton B = new JButton("continue");

   String pass;

public login()
{
    f.add(new JLabel("Login"));
    f.add(x);

    B.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(B);

    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setSize(500,300);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
            pass="pass";

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String textFieldValue = x.getText();

    if(textFieldValue==pass)
    {
        System.out.println("worked!");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    new login();


}

}
```

Comment: All you've done is post code and state "does not work". Please help us by defining "does not work" as this doesn't help us understand your problem. What do you expect this code to do that it is not doing? What is it currently doing that you don't want it to? Please spend a little time putting a little effort into asking your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for string comparisons in Java you should use the `String#equals(String s)` method, not the `"=="` operation. The `equals(...)` method tests to see if two Strings hold the same characters in the same order (what you desire). The `==` operation tests if the objects referred to by two String variales are one and the same (not what you desire).

This could be the problem, but your question is not that clear

Comment: You're probably right. I wish that we weren't required to guess at the problem though. 1+